# Как исправить ошибку history of undefined при использовании BrowserRouter из модуля react-router-dom версии 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Почему при использовании BrowserRouter изreact-router-dom версии 5 возникает ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

```
import React from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import About from './About';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )

    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно родителю передать

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();

<Parent history={history}>
 Ваши компоненты роутинга 
</Parent>
```

Вот официальная документация - [Тап](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router/history-object)

Answer (score 0):

Обернуть свой компонент в `withRouter()`;

```
export default withRouter(About);
```